# hacer un select con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Quiero editar elemento y para esto tengo que crear con `javascript` un `select` que con datos obtenidos de mi servidor muestre varios elementos obtenidos de la base de datos. Los datos los paso por json, son una serie x de datos, la tabla esta conformada por id y por el nombre de un municipio.

En controller

```
$municipios= Municipios::all();

return response()->json(['municipios' => $municipios]);
```

hasta el momento he podido hacer esto para editar pero no encuentro la forma de incluir el select en la siguiente linea de codigo.

```
function transformarEnEditable(nodo, id){

            id_venta = id;

            if (editando == false) {

                var nodoTd = nodo.parentNode; //Nodo TD

                var nodoTr = nodoTd.parentNode; //Nodo TR

                var nodosEnTr = nodoTr.getElementsByTagName('td');

                var lugar_trabajo = nodosEnTr[0].textContent;
                var ocupacion_laboral = nodosEnTr[1].textContent;

                var nuevoCodigoHtml =
                    '<tr id="actual">'+
                        '<td ><input type="text" name="numeracion" id="pagado_deuda" value="'+lugar_trabajo+'" size="15"></td>' +

                        '<td class="align-center"><input type="text" class="form-group" name="pagado_producto" id="pagado_producto" value="'+ ocupacion_laboral +'" size="15"></td>' +

                        '<td class="align-center"><a onclick="capturarEnvio()" class="green" title="Aceptar">' +
                        '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-check bigger-120"></i></a> ' +
                        '<a onclick="anular()" class="red" title="Cancelar"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-close bigger-120"></i></a></td>'+
                    '</tr>';

                nodoTr.innerHTML = nuevoCodigoHtml;

                editando = "true";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Pero como estas llamando al servidor y del lado del servidor que datos envias de respuesta?

Comment: Quieres crear un select? y el contenido de ese select editarlo? o una lista con los valores de tu base de datos para despues editarlos?

Comment: Quiero con una lista de valores obtengo crear un select, para cambiar el estado a un elemento.

Comment: Es mejor que edites la pregunta e indiques el JSON, o una parte representativa del mismo, que tienes para montar ese `select` que la parte del servidor que lo envía. Haz un *debug* de la respuesta en la consola del navegador por ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente ejemplo agrega un `select` a un `div` con `id="target"`:

```js
function agregarSelect() {
  var select = '<select><option value="uno">Uno</option><option value="dos">Dos</option></select>';
  document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = select;
}
```

```html
<button onClick="agregarSelect();">Modificar</button>
<div id="target">
Contenido inicial
</div>
```

Comment: gracias por su comentario pero en caso que tenga que agregar elementos de un arreglo obtenido de la base de datos. Sldos

Comment: @alberto Por favor edita tu pregunta para clarificar la ayuda que estás buscando.

Comment: Plantee el problema que tengo en el cuerpo de la pregunta cito "Quiero editar elemento y para esto tengo que crear con javascript un select que con datos obtenidos de mi servidor muestre varios elementos obtenidos de la base de datos." en el select

Comment: @albertolg89 ¿Cuáles son los tipos de dato de los datos de la lista? ¿los datos los tienes codificados, es decir, tienes diferenciado el parámetro de valor del `option` del texto a mostrar? ¿Cuántos datos son?

Comment: Los datos los paso por json, son una serie x de datos, la tabla esta conformada por id y por el nombre de un municipio

Comment: @albertolg89 agrega esos detalles a la pregunta, incluyendo un ejemplo el json.